# Detecting key press event in Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I'm trying to find a way to detect if a key (on a keyboard) has been pressed on Swift. Any ideas and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try yourself ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Objective-C answers are not duplicates for Swift questions.

Comment: In what context did you want to detect a key press? On a window? An input?

Comment: Hi Bjorn, just in a window. I wanted to add an if statement, such as 'if the key 'A' was pressed, do something' etc.

Comment: Ok, just for anyone else interested I gave the exact example for how to do this for a window below.

Comment: any way in iOS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you updated your question and you wanted to know how to do this for a window, here's an answer. Subclass NSWindow and use this subclass instead.

Your custom class should look like this:

```
import Cocoa

class EditorWindow: NSWindow {
    override func keyDown(event: NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(event)
        Swift.print("Caught a key down: \(event.keyCode)!")
    }
}
```

If you've made your window in Interface Builder/XCode, click the window object and go to the Attribute Inspector (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>). The Attribute Inspector will be in the sidebar on the right. Making sure your window is selected in Interface Builder, at the top of the Attribute Inspector in the `Custom Class` area put your new class in the class input.

[image: Attribute Selector]

In order to communicate the event from the this window class to my app I add a function to the window that accepts a callback function that I then store in an array of callback functions. I get access to this window through the AppDelegate which can get a weak reference to the current main window. Then in the above function I iterate overall the callbacks and call it with the NSEvent as the argument. I also first check to see if any command keys like the option keys are being pressed first through `modifierFlags` property on the event. It ends up looking like this:

```
import Cocoa

typealias Callback = (NSEvent) -> ()

class KeyCaptureWindow: NSWindow {

    var keyEventListeners = Array<Callback>()

    override func keyDown(event: NSEvent) {
        if event.modifierFlags.contains(NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask) {
            super.keyDown(event)
            return
        }
        for callback in keyEventListeners {
            callback(event)
        }
    }

    func addKeyEventCallback(callback: Callback) {
        keyEventListeners.append(callback)
    }


}
```

And then elsewhere in my code I have a line like so:

```
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let mainWindow = appDelegate.getWindow()
    mainWindow.addKeyEventCallback(handleKeyEvent)
```

I added the `getWindow` method to my app delegate class. This method returns the `NSWindow` cast to `KeyCaptureWindow`. There may be a better way to do all this but this works for me. Another way to possibly do this is to use first responders and `NSView`, but that's not how I've been doing it.

Comment: If there are multiple keyboards connected to the computer, is it possible to identift which keyboard the even came from?

Comment: Recent versions of Swift have modified the function. It's now keyDown(with event: NSEvent). Thanks for the answer, very informative!

Answer (score 7):

You have to override the `keyDown`-method.

```
var direction:String = ""

override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) // A key is pressed
{
    if theEvent.keyCode == 123
    {
        direction = "left" //get the pressed key
    }
    else if theEvent.keyCode == 124
    {
        direction = "right" //get the pressed key
    }
    println("Key with number: \(theEvent.keyCode) was pressed")
}
```