# Check if the u key is pressed Swift Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, key

I'm trying to detect if the `U` key is pressed or not, and if it is it should `print("BUT...BUT..");` but I'm not sure how to check for different keys, as the documentation for key presses is quite bad.. I found an answer with keycodes but they only work for QWERTY keyboards

*viewcontroller.swift*

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad();
    let f = Foo();
    f.doSonethimg();
}

override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent){
    let f = Foo();
    f.KeyDown(theEvent);
}
```

*Foo.swift*

```
public func doSonething(){
    print("Hello from Dylib");
}

public func keyDown(event: NSEvent){
        if let keyString = theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers where keyString == "u" || keyString == "U" {
    Swift.print("BUT...BUT…")
}
}
```

How would I change the `keyDown` Function to respond to `U` and what is it's default key?

I've looked at - [Detecting key press event in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158964/detecting-key-press-event-in-swift) and https://superuser.com/questions/399430/mouse-button-and-keypress-counter-for-mac-os-x

also see - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html - Overriding the keyDown: Method

Comment: Consider that the behavior of the function keys (as F-keys) depends on a setting in System Preferences

Comment: that's true, thank you i'll update my question accordingly

Comment: Did you read the documentation of NSEvent? NSEvent has methods for Getting Key Event Information, like `characters`. Keydown events don't have a default key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily check for a character by using `NSEvent`s `charactersIgnoringModifiers` property.

```
func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if let keyString = theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers where keyString == "u" || keyString == "U" {
        Swift.print("BUT...BUT…")
    }
}
```

Note: There is a difference between checking for 'u' and 'U'. They are modified by <kbd>Shift</kbd>. So if you want to have both recognized, check for both. *(as in the example above)*

**Responder Chain**: 
The keyDown function is only called when the view or viewController participates in the so called [Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html).

To set up your viewController for being part of the Responder Chain, read the following [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW11).

Comment: The keyDown event in my viewcontroller is never called so it won't enter the if do you know why this is?