# Single key press input

Tags: swift, macos, uikeyboard

I'm trying to write a Swift program which accepts input from the keyboard --- specifically, I want the computer to act as soon as a single key is pressed. So the user doesn't have to press Enter after the keypress.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if the u key is pressed Swift Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911418/check-if-the-u-key-is-pressed-swift-cocoa)

Comment: Okay so I put the following code in my an empty main.swift file.  Then I run the program but nothing happens.  import AppKit

func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if let keyString = theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers where keyString == "u" || keyString == "U" {
        Swift.print("BUT...BUT…")
    }
}

Comment: Are you typing into a text input field or just using key commands?

Comment: @John I don't think I understand your question.  As an experiment I added the following code --- var goof : NSEvent
keyDown(goof)
This gives the error that I'm using the variable goof before it is initialized but I don't know how to initialize an NSEvent

Comment: Ok. It's probably my fault that you don't recognize that, since I'm an iOS developer and didn't realize this was a Mac question until too late...

Comment: This might help you (sorry that it's in objc): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164471/listen-to-a-value-change-of-my-text-field