# Interaction between Window, ViewController and custom View

Tags: swift, macos, viewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm creating an application which would act like a text editor. However, I can't use existing controls for text areas, because the text would consist of compound characters ("a" above "b", which is at top-right of "c", etc...).
So I need to listen for keystrokes - that's work for `NSWindow` (see [Bjorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28174142/4642081)).
Then I have a regular `NSViewController` and custom `RichCharacterView`.
My custom `NSWindow` is already a class of the storyboard's window and so is `RichCharacterView` of SB's view.

What I just can't figure out is **how to pass data between those**. Does it manage AppDelegate? How do I tell my `ViewController` that its `self.view` is not a `NSView` but `RichCharacterView`?

Comment: What is RichCharacterView?

Comment: @ElTomato My custom NSView subclass.