# How to detect arrow keys when subclassing a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard, subclass

Basically, I want to do something when one of the arrow keys are pressed.

I've read many different questions. Many of them talk about `keyDown`, but that is for `NSViewController` or `NSWindow`([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158964/detecting-key-press-event-in-swift) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html)(Apple Documention)). I thought I was onto something when I used this:

```
func setKeys() {
    let up = UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(upPressed))
}

@objc func upPressed() {
    print("Hello")
}
```

However, the `upPressed()` isn't even called. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the returned UIKeyCommand instance `up`.

Apple: "After creating a key command object, you can add it to a view controller using the addKeyCommand: method of the view controller. You can also override any responder class and return the key command directly from the responder’s keyCommands property."

```
class Test: UIViewController{

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       setKeys()
   }

   func setKeys() {
      let up = UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(upPressed))
      self.addKeyCommand(up)
   }

   @objc func upPressed() {
      print("Hello")
   }
}
```

Tested this using a simulator and hardware keyboard.

ADDITIONALLY: If you are going to implement it through the UIView directly you have to do : "...You can also override any responder class and return the key command directly from the responder’s keyCommands property." since UIView conforms to UIResponder

```
class CustomView: UIView{
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
       return  [UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(upPressed))]
    }

    @objc func upPressed(){
        print("hello world")
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems, that this solution no longer works. Tried on iOS 15.5 with external bluetooth keyboard. Other `UIKeyCommand` input strings works fine (e.g. inputEscape, ...), but not the Up/Down/Left/Right keys.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to work on iOS/iPadOS using a view controller. The key is leveraging `wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior`:

```swift
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    let upArrow = UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(test))
    upArrow.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior = true

    return [upArrow]
}

@objc func test(_ sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print(">>> test was pressed")
}
```