# SwiftUI KeyboardShortcut with Arrow Keys

Tags: swiftui

I’m having trouble using an arrow key as a `.keyboardShortcut` in SwiftUI. Sample iOS app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var time: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Press Me") {
                time = Date()
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent.rightArrow, modifiers: [])
        
            Text("\(time)")
        }
    }
}
```

This puts up a button that, when pressed, changes the time displayed in the `text`. I should be able to use the right arrow key on the keyboard and get it to work as well, but it doesn’t. If I change the `keyboardShortcut` line to, say, this:

```
.keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(“a”), modifiers: [])
```

everything works as expected. You can press the “a” key and the time changes. If you hold down the command key, you get the system-provided HUD that shows the “a" shortcut. Change it to `.rightAarrow` and it shows the HUD but there’s an enclosed “?” for the shortcut, and the shortcut doesn’t fire when the arrow key is pressed.

(I’m aware I could do this using `UIKit`. Trying to understand why the SwiftUI version doesn’t work.)

Answer (score 6):

I am attempting to accomplish the same objective in my MacOS SwiftUI app.  Using your code as an example, I inserted the `.keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent.rightArrow, modifiers: [])` after my `Button{}` and it works fine.  I then pasted your entire code into my ContentView and again it works fine.  I do not know why it works in my MacOS app but not in your iOS app.

Comment: I’ve replicated this. The code works in MacOS, not in iOS.

Comment: Same. Arrow keys are recognized in MacOS, ignored in iOS.  Has anyone stumbled upon a solution?  The bug has persisted for more than a year now it seems.

Comment: Any luck with new WWDC's beta?

Comment: As of iOS 16 beta 4, this still doesn't seem to work. I've submitted feedback (FB11131062)

Comment: For me arrows don't work in a Mac Catalyst app. I presume this is because it might be put on an iPad and these arrows don't work on iPads?

Answer (score 2):

Copying my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370534/7396787). I wasn't able to use SwiftUI's commands to get this to work on iOS/iPadOS. However I found some luck using view controllers, and if you're using SwiftUI views then this will work with a [hosting controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller).

In your view controller, add the code below. The important bit is setting `wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior` to true:

```swift
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    let upArrow = UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(test))
    upArrow.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior = true

    return [upArrow]
}

@objc func test(_ sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print(">>> test was pressed")
}
```